Why can't I get my ASP.NET web app to work with IT FoxTec SAML?
I have an older service provider web app running a mix of ASP.NET 4.8 and .NET Core 2.0.
I am trying to integrate the ITFoxTec SAML package into it.
I have everything working except a method in my MetadataController class.
I have this in my MetadataController.cs:
I am getting this error:
  The type or namespace name 'ServiceName' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

    

Here is everything I am importing:
using ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Schemas.Metadata;
using ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Schemas;
using ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.MvcCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

And here is the problem area:
  public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var defaultSite = new Uri($"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host.ToUriComponent()}/");

        var entityDescriptor = new EntityDescriptor(config);
        entityDescriptor.ValidUntil = 365;
        entityDescriptor.SPSsoDescriptor = new SPSsoDescriptor
        {
            WantAssertionsSigned = false,
            
            AssertionConsumerServices = new AssertionConsumerService[]
            {
                new AssertionConsumerService { Binding = ProtocolBindings.HttpPost, Location = new Uri(defaultSite, "Auth/AssertionConsumerService") },
            },
            AttributeConsumingServices = new AttributeConsumingService[]
            {   // It doesn't recognize 'ServiceName'
                new AttributeConsumingService { ServiceName = new ServiceName("LegacyEnrollmentArea", "en"), RequestedAttributes = CreateRequestedAttributes() }
            },
        };

Is there any way to fix it?

You should first update the ASP.NET Core project from 2.0 to 3.1 or later - it should be straightforward and will eliminate loads of other problems. BTW, the authentication model was changed between 1.0, 2.0 and 3.x, so that could be part of it too.

Also, is there a reason you're using ITfoxtec.Identity over MS's own SAML lib? (I'm not familiar with it), but if you're having problems it might be an idea to stay first-party at first.

@Dai I didn't know MS had their own SAML library...do you know what it's called?  It might not be compatible with my legacy app though.

I was confused, sorry - while there is the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml package, there isn't a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Saml package, unfortunately.

The type ServiceName was changed to the type LocalizedNameType in ITfoxtec.Identity.SAML version 4.11.1.
It's a braking change, I'm afraid, to comply more strictly with the SAML 2.0 standard.
-------- edited --------
Changed code:
AttributeConsumingServices =
[
    new AttributeConsumingService { ServiceNames = [new LocalizedNameType("Some SP", "en")], RequestedAttributes = CreateRequestedAttributes() }
]

Code sample link https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/main/test/TestWebAppCore/Controllers/MetadataController.cs#L49

Thank you.  So it should look like this?
            `AttributeConsumingServices = new AttributeConsumingService`
            {
                `new AttributeConsumingService { LocalizedNameType ` 

= new LocalizedNameType ("LegacyEnrollmentArea", "en"), RequestedAttributes = CreateRequestedAttributes() }
  },

Yes, it looks correct.
